# Can't Understand Glib Error

Tags: c, glib

I am making use of the glib 2.0 framework. After some time, my C program outputs this error:

> GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_foreach_remove_or_steal: assertion
>   `version == hash_table->version' failed

Can anybody tell me what this means in general? Google hasnt really helped much. Thank you

Comment: Usually means you are causing the structure of the table to go out of sync. (Like removing items while iterating over the table, etc..)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Google search with the text you provided produced:

> This usually indicates that you did a g_hash_table_remove() (or
>   g_hash_table_insert(), g_hash_table_replace() or similar) while
>   iterating over the same hash table. I didn't spot where this could
>   happen.

Taken from [here](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/telepathy-bugs/2012-September/020133.html).

Hopefully, you now have enough information to find the error in your code.

Comment: does this also apply for when iterating over lists such as GSList ?